# Listing subclasses without knowing explicitly about them

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance

Suppose I have an abstract class IceCream that VanillaIceCream and StrawberryIceCream inherits from. I also have an IceCreamView that holds reference to the abstract class IceCream (i.e. only uses the common properties of all types of ice creams). However, I also need to implement a combo box in the view where users can select the type of IceCream they want to create; the available types should be determined by the subclasses of IceCream.

My question is: is there any way in which I can list all subclasses of IceCream in this view without explicitly knowing about them in either the abstract superclass and the View?

The background to my problem is that I want to be able to extend the functionality in the future (add more types of ice cream) without changing the existing code.

The only solutions I've come up with that all breaks this assumption are:
1) Manually enter the names of the subclasses in the View.
2) Reference to the subclasses instead of(/in addition to) the abstract superclass in the View.
3) Create an enumeration in the superclass that list all subclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Reflection. Use the following method:

```
''' <summary>
''' Retrieves all subclasses of the specified type.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="baseType">The base type.</param>
''' <param name="onlyDirectSubclasses">Indicates whether only the direct subclasses
''' should be retrieved. If set to <see langword="false"/>, then all, also
''' indirect subclasses will be retrieved.</param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Function GetSubclasses(ByVal baseType As Type, ByVal onlyDirectSubclasses As Boolean) As List(Of Type)
    Dim res As New List(Of Type)

    For Each asm As Reflection.Assembly In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        For Each typ As Type In asm.GetTypes()
            If onlyDirectSubclasses Then
                If typ.BaseType Is baseType Then
                    res.Add(typ)
                End If
            Else
                If typ.IsSubclassOf(baseType) Then
                    res.Add(typ)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Return res
End Function
```

And then call it:

```
Dim subclasses As List(Of Type) = GetSubclasses(GetType(IceCream), False)
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which language you are writing in.  Some languages make that easy to inspect at run time, others make it easy enough to have each concrete class register itself, and some have totally novel features.  So what are you writing in, more specifically than some language that has inheritance and maybe uses the nomenclature of "super/sub class"?

Comment: I am using VB.NET in this case.